# Visual Basic System Information

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, system-information

I want to make a button and display the System Information from Windows.How can I do it?How can i call that info?Thank you very much.

Is it possible to make something like this?

http://s18.postimage.org/7zn5adst3/Memory.jpg

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Shell("msinfo32.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: :Thank you very much for your quick answer.Problem Solved.

Comment: Is it possible to make something like this in vb.net? http://s18.postimage.org/7zn5adst3/Memory.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Shell has now been updated and is no longer used. So, the process would be `process.start("msinfo32.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)`